How to play hold music on both sides of a call using Twilio in Laravel?
Question:
When I click on the hold button, I want to play hold music on both sides: on the dialer and on the user's mobile phone. Currently, I'm facing a problem: when I use the dialer's callSid, the music plays only on the dialer's side, and the call is disconnected on the user's phone. When I use the user's callSid, the call is disconnected on the dialer side and music plays on the user's phone. How can I simultaneously put the call on hold on both sides and play hold music on both?
**Laravel code **
    $phoneNumber = $request->input('to');
    $dialerCallSid = $request->input('callSid');
    $calls = $this->twilio->calls->read([
        'to' => $phoneNumber,
        'status' => 'in-progress'
    ]);

    \Log::info("here is call deatisl =>". print_r($calls, true));

    if (!empty($calls)) {        
        $userCallSid = $calls[0]->sid;
        \Log::info("here is call deatisl =>". $userCallSid);
        $dialerSideHold = $this->twilio->calls('CA52e6180d8267befb7a3fdc7dbc0f0e35')
        ->update([
            'twiml' => '<Response><Play>http://com.twilio.music.classical.s3.amazonaws.com/BusyStrings.mp3</Play></Response>'
        ]);            

        return response()->json(['message' => 'Call put on hold successfully']);
    }

**Vue js code **
  const user = await User.auth();      
  const userId = user.data.id;
  axiosIns.post('/place-on-hold', {
      callSid: callSid.value,
      to: userNumber.value,
      From: from.value,
  })
  .then(response => {
      console.log(response.data.message);
  })
  .catch(error => {
      console.error(error.response.data.error);
  });
}

I am using ngrok, not a localhost URL. I need functionality where if the agent puts the call on hold during the conversation, the call does not disconnect, and music plays on both sides.
What I've tried:
Using the dialer's callSid only plays music on the dialer's side and disconnects the user's call.
Using the user's callSid disconnects the dialer's side.
Environment:
Can someone help me figure out how to properly put the call on hold on both sides and play hold music for both parties?
